# Could not run SORM examples

Tags: sorm

I ran into a problem testing the nice SORM lib.

When I try to run code like this:

```
case class Coffee(name: String, supplier: Supplier, price: Double, sales: Int, total: Int)
case class Supplier(name: String, street: String, city: String, state: String, zip: String)

object Db extends Instance(
  entities = Set(Entity[Coffee](), Entity[Supplier]()),
  url = "jdbc:h2:mem:play",
  initMode = InitMode.Create
)

val supplier1 = Supplier("Acme, Inc.", "99 Market Street", "Groundsville", "CA", "95199")
Db.save(supplier1)
```

I get exceptions like this:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106) ~[mchange-commons-java-0.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:641) ~[c3p0-0.9.2-pre5.jar:0.9.2-pre5]
```

I use Play 2.10 and my DB config looks like this:

```
 db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
 db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
# db.default.user=sa
# db.default.password=""
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does it have to do with Play?

Comment: Yes, you are right with this comment, too. I removed the play tag. As you can see from my comment to your answer below, I thought it has something to do with the play framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code runs absolutely fine. The problem must be somewhere in your setup. E.g., to be able to use H2 database you need to include it in your project's dependencies.

In the Maven project in which I successfully tested your code I had the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
  <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.168</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I thought h2 is somehow included in the playframework, so that I don't need any dependency entry. So, that was completely my fault, after I added something like '"com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.3.168"' to the dependency list in project/Build.scala, it runs fine.